# Split the combine data(Numeric and Sting) to separate data through PHP

Tags: php

How can i split string data 'VAL001' to two columns 'VAL' and '001' in PHP.

Comment: Regular expressions, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = 'VAL001';
$val1 = substr( $var, 0,3);
$val2 = substr( $var, 3,3);

echo $val1." ".$val2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options, but you'll notice pretty quickly that we need more criteria than Numeric and String, as one does not exclude the other, some strings are numeric and all numbers can be strings.

[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

[substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function getParts($str){
    $pieces = preg_split("/[A-Z]+/", $str);
    $number = $pieces[1];
    $pieces = preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $str);
    $string = $pieces[0];   
    return array('number' => $number, 'string' => $string);
}
$str1 = 'VAL001';
$str2 = 'NEWVAL0001';

$ret1 = getParts($str1);
var_dump($ret1);
$ret2 = getParts($str2);
var_dump($ret2);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(2) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(3) "001"
  ["string"]=>
  string(3) "VAL"
}
array(2) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(4) "0001"
  ["string"]=>
  string(6) "NEWVAL"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on what you need.  I'll give you an answer no one has yet: [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
list($val, $num) = str_split($string, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark for above solutions with 100000 iterations.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2435M CPU @ 2.40GHz

```
<?php
function getParts($str){
    $pieces = preg_split("/[A-Z]+/", $str);
    $number = $pieces[1];
    $pieces = preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $str);
    $string = $pieces[0];   
    return array('number' => $number, 'string' => $string);
}

$string = 'VAL001';

$start = microtime(true);
for($cou=0;$cou<100000;$cou++){
    $ret = getParts($string);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken : ' .  sprintf('%f', $end - $start);
echo "\n";


$start = microtime(true);
for($cou=0;$cou<100000;$cou++){
    list($val, $num) = str_split($string, 3);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'time taken : ' .  sprintf('%f', $end - $start);
echo "\n";


$start = microtime(true);
for($cou=0;$cou<100000;$cou++){
    $val1 = substr( $var, 0,3);
    $val2 = substr( $var, 3,3);
}
echo 'time taken : ' .  sprintf('%f', $end - $start);
echo "\n";
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

first run

```
time taken : 2.269323
time taken : 0.586926
time taken : -0.000081
```

second run

```
time taken : 2.205317
time taken : 0.555085
time taken : -0.000073
```